# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have my project ready and I have just uploaded to a shared hosting server. Everything works perfectly fine on my local machine but the page is displaying the error:
 "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I have checked my password and username and they are both correct. The server requirements are also as I already have 2 other Laravel sites running with the same host.

I have done php artisan config:cache php artisan cache:clear But no headway.

What could be causing this and how do I get it solved? I earnestly need a solutions as this has kept me sleepless for nights now.

Comment: did you checkt .evn file and credential there  ?

Comment: try accessing your database manually if it throws the same error. I had the same error once and it is because of the database itself not laravel

Comment: show us .env file

Comment: Seems you are using wrong details in your .env file. Do check it again.

Comment: you should add you env file setting here so we could see the problem

Answer (score 2):

try to with these 3 artisan command.

1) `php artisan config:clear`

2) `php artisan cache:clear`

3) `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: here is my db details in the .env fileDB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cabyzen
DB_USERNAME=cabyzen
DB_PASSWORD=@xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: are you try to with these all above command one by one, i hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I just changed the content of the .env file with the one on my local machine and confirmed the database username and password again but to no avail. I am still having this error.

Comment: confirmed local machine has by default, username: root & password: <nothing>

Comment: I think the server is not seeing my .env file. What could be the reason for this

Comment: or only `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

different config? it's saying your password is empty ;)

"I have checked my password and username"

"(using password: NO)"

app/config/database.php:

```
    'mysql' => array(
    'read' => array(
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ),
    'write' => array(
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '<insert password here?>',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Comment: did you misspell password in the config? cause you mysql says it doesnt get a password

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

It will prompt you in mysql, here you can fire any mysql commands.

Use mysql table for change table type, so we can use empty password. Bellow is command for it

```
USE mysql;
```

Now we change type of table by following command

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

now we have to flush the privileges, because we have used UPDATE. If you use INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE on grant tables directly you need use FLUSH PRIVILEGES in order to reload the grant tables.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

now exit from mysql by following command

```
exit;
```

now restart mysql server by following command

```
service mysql restart
```

Hope this may help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you deploy a project, you should typically run the php artisan config:cache command as part of your production deployment routine. I suggest you

1. Remove the configuration cache file
2. Flush the application cache
3. Create a cache file for faster configuration loading

To do this, run the following Artisan commands on your command line

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Where you don't have access to the command line on your server, you can programmatically execute commands by adding the following to your routes:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

And then call the clear-cache route from your browser.

Comment: Thank you all. This has been fixed. php artisan cache:clear is all that is needed. php artisan config:cache was my problem. this second command cached the database parameters that got uploaded to the server which overrides the parameters set in the .env files. So all I did was to run php artisan cache:clear, then re-uploaded. Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I added "" to password in .env file and it worked